# array merge function is not working in while loop

Tags: php

I am using two queries in while loop,so as a result getting two arrays, and I want 
to merge them into single array. Here is my code. Please tell me where I am wrong ?

```
<?php
While ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) {
    $res1 = mysql_query("select * from tablename where ... ");
    $res11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $res2 = mysql_query("select * from tablename where ... ");
    $res22 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
}
total = array_merge($res11, $res22);
$responseJSON = array(
    "response" => total
);
header("content - type: application / json");
response = json_encode($responseJSON);
echo response;
```

Comment: Curly quotes `“ ”` - *Beautiful, yet deadly*. Use regular quotes `"`. checking for errors would have thrown you parse errors. Don't code with "Word", use a code "editor".

Comment: You don't have a merge in the while loop, it's outside.

Comment: `total=array_merge` that `total` is missing the `$` and is treated as a constant... IF that's your real code.

Comment: You have lots of syntax errors in your code: write $total instead of total, $response instead of response.

Comment: What you are doing must be wrong, you are restarting the select every time the while loop is executed, and thus receive always the first result from the query.

Answer (score 0):

before while initialize $res11 = []; and $res22 = [] ;

```
 $res11[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)
 $res22[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
```

write like these and try.

Comment: you missed a LOT of stuff

Comment: use the same code what u posted just replace these variables . You will get it

Comment: I'm not the person who posted the question.

Comment: If i use [] then i have print result two time

Comment: check your query once if you use like that it will just add the value to the array only.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell what you want to do, my guess is this:

```
$query8 = mysql_query("select * from table name where ...");

$res1 = array();
$res2 = array();
while($row0=mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) {
    $res1[] = $row0;
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)
    $res2[] = $row1;
  }

$total=array_merge($res1,$res2);

$responseJSON = array("response" => $total);

header("content-type:application/json");

$response = json_encode($responseJSON);

echo $response;
```